# Validation rule - Salesforce CPQ Contracted checkbox

Tags: validation-rule, cpq

I want to write a validation rule on the Opportunity record -
Condition:- User can only check the contracted checkbox if the opportunity stage is closed won and primary quote (lookup field) - status field is approved. Can someone help me.

I wrote this, but this doesn't work

```
AND(
    SBQQ__Contracted__c = TRUE,
    TEXT(StageName) <> "Closed",
    TEXT(SBQQ__PrimaryQuote__r.SBQQ__Status__c) <> "Approved"
)
```

If I consider only opp stagename as condition - it works.. but once I add the primary quote condition my logic fails

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `SBQQ_PrimaryQuote__c` is a lookup field on the `Opportunity`, and that this field is populated.

Remember the first law of validation rules

> validation rules don't tell you when your data is valid.
> **They tell you when your data is *invalid*.**

If your condition for data to be valid is
`when SBQQ__Contracted__c is true, Opp stage must be closed and primary quote must be approved`

then the condition for when data is invalid is
`when SBQQ__Contracted__c is true, and Opp stage is not closed **or** primary quote is not approved`

From basic boolean algebra, De Morgan's law states that `NOT(AND(X, Y))` === `OR(NOT(X), NOT(Y))`. That's why the invalid state swaps the inner "and" with an "or"

So your formula should be

```
AND(
    /* No need to compare a checkbox to true/false, because it's already boolean */
    SBQQ__Contracted__c,
    OR(
        TEXT(StageName) != "Closed",
        TEXT(SBQQ__PrimaryQuote__r.SBQQ__Status__c) != "Approved"
    )
)
```